# python | tkinter and threading: "main thread is not in main loop"

Tags: python, multithreading, canvas, tkinter

I'm working on an "multilayered" GUI for my company to monitor temperature and status. Because I'm quite new to the python programming, I could use some help with my code.

### Quick code explanation:

The code is structured by classes. The "Main" inits the main window (tkinter) and creates the other frames to display if wanted. Every other class, except "canvas", is a frame which will display different things.

The canvas in each contains an image and some text/variable text.
A thread is used to get data from a database and change the text in the canvas.

## The Problem:

Every time, the thread accessed the canvas and tries to change the text or create an new one, the error `"main thread is not in main loop"` is thrown.

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 920, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Programme/MM/TEST_Dateien/TEST_QUEUE.py", line 154, in __call__
    canvUbersicht.create_text(500,500, text="HOIIIIII")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2345, in create_text
    return self._create('text', args, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2321, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

If I init the thread without calling the canvas (e.g. `"print("hey")`), everything works fine.

Where does my mainloop / mainthread begin and where do they end?

I have already read several Questions and rearranged the code / thread, but it won't change anything.

I would be really happy, if someone could help me.

**important code:**

```
from tkinter import*
from DataSQL import*

class Main(Tk):
    def __init__(self, vollbild=False):
        print("Main INIT")
        Tk.__init__(self)                               #Initialisieren von Tkinter und somit erzeugen des Fensters
        Tk.geometry(self, ("1920x1080"))                #setzen von verschiedenen Parametern für das Fenster
        Tk.title(self, ("Laborüberwachung"))
        Tk.wm_overrideredirect(self, vollbild)

        container = Frame(self)                             #Frame "container" wird im eigenen Objekt(also main fenster) erstellt
        container.pack(side="top",fill="both",expand=True)  #Platzieren des Frames und ausfüllen des ganzen Fensters
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)            #Platzieren im Grid
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)         #Platzieren im Grid
        
        self.frames = {}                                #Erstellt leere Liste
        
        for F in (Ubersicht, Settings, Pin, BR167, BR213, Star3, Telematik):
            frame = F(container, self)                  #Objekt frame wird erzeugt durch aufruf von Konstruktoren der Klassen(Frameklassen zB "Übersicht")
            self.frames[F] = frame                      #Objekte werden in der Liste gespeichert, unter dem Namen der Klasse(zB "frames[Übersicht]")
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")  #Platzieren des Frames im Grid, wobei das Grid aus nur einem Feld besteht, wird nur für die Funktionalität benötigt

        self.show_frame(Ubersicht)                      #Zeigt immer die Übersichtsseite bei StartUp
        #print(self.frames)

    def show_frame(self, cnt):                         #Methode zum Framewechsel und somit umschalten zwischen 'Tabs'
        frame = self.frames[cnt]
        frame.tkraise()
        print("frame raised",cnt)


class Ubersicht(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        print("Ubersicht INIT")
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        self.interfaceImage = PhotoImage(file="/home/pi/Documents/Programme/Laborueberwachung3/IMG 1080/Übersicht.png")
        canvUbersicht = canv(self, controller, img=self.interfaceImage, Uber=1)
 
        self.__eventExit = threading.Event()
        self.__thread = threading.Thread(target=self, args=(canvUbersicht, self.__eventExit,))
        self.__thread.start()
        
    def __call__(self,canvUbersicht,stop_event):
        while not stop_event.wait(1):
            canvUbersicht.create_text(500,500,text="HEY")

class canv(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, img=None, Uber=None):
        Canvas.__init__(self, parent)
        print("canvas INIT")
        self.config(width=1920,height=1080)
        self.place(x=0,y=0)
        if (img != None):
            self.create_image(0,0,anchor=NW,image=img)
            
        if (Uber == 1):
            clickAreaSettings = self.create_rectangle(0,0,350,60, fill="", outline="")
            self.tag_bind(clickAreaSettings, '<Button-1>',lambda event: controller.show_frame(Pin))
        else:
            clickAreaBack = self.create_rectangle(0,0,350,60, fill="", outline="")
            self.tag_bind(clickAreaBack,'<Button-1>', lambda event: controller.show_frame(Ubersicht)) 

        clickAreaBR167 = self.create_rectangle(0,60,350,315, fill="", outline="")
        clickAreaBR213 = self.create_rectangle(0,316,350,570, fill="", outline="")
        clickAreaStar3 = self.create_rectangle(0,571,350,825, fill="", outline="")
        clickAreaTelematik = self.create_rectangle(0,826,350,1080, fill="", outline="")
        self.tag_bind(clickAreaBR167,'<Button-1>', lambda event: controller.show_frame(BR167))
        self.tag_bind(clickAreaBR213,'<Button-1>', lambda event: controller.show_frame(BR213))
        self.tag_bind(clickAreaStar3,'<Button-1>', lambda event: controller.show_frame(Star3))
        self.tag_bind(clickAreaTelematik,'<Button-1>', lambda event: controller.show_frame(Telematik))
       
app = Main(vollbild=False)
app.mainloop
```

Comment: maybe thread try to use tkinter elements before `mainloop()` starts and creates them. Maybe try to use `sleep()` in thread so `mainloop()` will have time to create all objects.

Comment: You've posted way too much code. Please condense that down into a [mcve]

Comment: I think tkinter does not support changes to the GUI made from threads different from the main one (the one where `mainloop` runs). So you need to find a way to avoid changing the GUI from the other threads. For instance, you can use `after` in the main thread to check if the other thread is finished (see the second part of my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47307157/python-tkinter-destroy-toplevel-after-function/47307404#47307404))

Comment: ok thank you for your answeres. 
I shortened the code to the (near) minimum.

@furas i tried it, didn't work

Comment: have you considered using only `.after` for database polling? It should be enough.

Answer (score 6):

> Where does my mainloop / mainthread begin and where do they end?

The main thread is all the code that you don't explicitly call in another thread.

Tkinter is single-threaded, and all access to widgets must be from the same thread. When you do `self.__thread = threading.Thread(target=self, ...)` you are causing some tkinter code to run in another thread.

You will need to rewrite your application so that the data gathering is in a separate thread which communicates with the main GUI thread via a thread-safe queue. You can push information on the queue from the thread, and the gui thread can poll the queue.

Comment: Is there any possibility to get the single thread  working with little changes to the code ? Or is it easier to code in a queue ?